# Limiting new choices on forms based on previous choices (Cognito Forms)

Tags: cognito-forms

I am setting up an electives class form for middle school using Cognito Forms.

We change what electives are available every two-to-three months.

I've set up already the first form for the first round of choices, but would like help setting up for the second round (and for the future).

If a student has already selected a STEM class with Mr. Smith, I want to make it so they are unable to choose Mr. Smith in my new form for the second round. This way, new students can try Mr. Smith's elective.

Is this possible with Cognito Forms? I was looking up the documentation for Lookup Fields, but I am very new to using Cognito Forms and am looking to see if this is even possible.

Thank you so much and hope to hear from you all soon.